# The function Norm is giving complex numbers as output

Tags: complex, linear-algebra

I'm trying to find the norm of a complex vector

```
$Assumptions = \[Phi] \[Element] Reals && \[Theta] \[Element] Reals;
\[CapitalDelta] = 2.5 \[Pi];
FullSimplify[Norm[1/Sqrt[2] ( {
  {Cos[\[Theta]]^2, Cos[\[Theta]] Sin[\[Theta]] },
  {Cos[\[Theta]] Sin[\[Theta]] , Sin[\[Theta]]^2}
 } ).( {
  {Cos[\[CapitalDelta]/2] + 
    I Sin[\[CapitalDelta]/2] Cos[2 \[Phi]], 
   I Sin[\[CapitalDelta]/2] Sin[2 \[Phi]] },
  {I Sin[\[CapitalDelta]/2] Sin[2 \[Phi]], 
   Cos[\[CapitalDelta]/2] - I Sin[\[CapitalDelta]/2] Cos[2 \[Phi]]}
 } ).( {
  {1},
  {I}
 } )]^2]
```

I was surprised to get a complex output as follows:

```
0.5 - 1.38778*10^-17 Cos[2 \[Theta] - 2 \[Phi]] + (0. + 5.55112*10^-17 I) Cos[2 \[Phi]]+ (0.5 + 1.38778*10^-17 I) Sin[2 \[Theta] - 2 \[Phi]] - 1.11022*10^-16 Cos[\[Phi]] Sin[\[Phi]]
```

because as far as I know, the Norm of a complex vector should always be Real.
Could you please give an explanation?

Here's a clear image in Matrix Form
[image]

Comment: Add `//Chop` at the end of your calculation to get rid of the small spurious imaginary parts resulting from machine-precision errors. Or alternatively use exact numbers like `5/2 Pi` instead of `2.5 Pi` and the problem will go away as well.

Comment: @MarcoB many folks who used things like Matlab and Python before and come to Mathematica do not yet appreciate the important difference between exact numbers and real numbers. in Matlab, it is all floating points numbers as the default. Writing `1` or `1.0` in Matlab is the same thing. Unless one works hard and use their  symbolic toolbox to make sure the numbers are made exact. But once they come back to the standard Matlab environment, these become floating points again.

Answer (score 1):

MarcoB comment:
Add //Chop at the end of your calculation to get rid of the small spurious imaginary parts resulting from machine-precision errors. Or alternatively use exact numbers like 5/2 Pi instead of 2.5 Pi and the problem will go away as well